# Customising a view with monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a view in a monotouch app I'm developing that simply has a number of buttons on it. The idea is that when I click on one of the buttons, a subview is opened from the bottom (like a keyboard) that has things like sliders and textviews on them (each button has a different subview that slides in).

I've looked around and can't seem to find how this can be done. I know it's possible as I've seen it on quite a few apps.

Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe what you need is actionsheet?

Comment: Try to set `InputView` to your custom view for `UITextView`s in your view. When some of them will receive a focus, `InputView` will be shown instead of default keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like a [UIActionSheet](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T:MonoTouch.UIKit.UIActionSheet). If that doesn't suit your needs, it's trivial to create a new `UIView` and make it appear -- just set its `Frame` property and use `AddSubview` (perhaps with an animation to make it slide up).

```
protected void HandleBtnActionSheetWithOtherButtonsTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   actionSheet = new UIActionSheet ("action sheet with other buttons");
   actionSheet.AddButton ("delete");
   actionSheet.AddButton ("cancel");
   actionSheet.AddButton ("a different option!");
   actionSheet.AddButton ("another option");
   actionSheet.DestructiveButtonIndex = 0;
   actionSheet.CancelButtonIndex = 1;
   //actionSheet.FirstOtherButtonIndex = 2;
   actionSheet.Clicked += delegate(object a, UIButtonEventArgs b) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Button " + b.ButtonIndex.ToString () + " clicked");
   };
   actionSheet.ShowInView (View);
}
```

[image: UIActionSheet]